# Understand Strlen applied to int array with char * cast

Tags: c, pointers, strlen

I'm currently stuck on this problem.

I have thefollowing code:

```
    int v[10] = {-1, 1000, 2};
    
    int a;
    
    a = strlen((char *)v+1);
    
    printf("strlen result for (char *) v+1: %d\n", a);
```

I cannot undestand why the final result is always 5 on a little endian "machine".
According to strlen documentation, the char * cast in this situation should return 4.

I tried also in online compiler and other machines but the result remains the same. What am I missing ?

Comment: You can't use `strlen()` on something that is not a C string, it's undefined behaviour. If you're leaning on the fact that there's `0x00` bytes in there due to how `int` is encoded, that's certainly something you can do, but it's not the intended use-case for this function. The behaviour you'll experience here is dependent on many factors, not the least of which is what `int` is on your system, what endian mode is used, etc.

Comment: "According to strlen documentation, the char * cast in this situation should return 4." Please elaborate on how you came to this conclusion.

Comment: Look at the raw memory as bytes before making any statements about what it should return.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  If you're trying to determine the size of the array `v` without using `sizeof`, that's one question.  If you're exploring the byte-by-byte representation of an array of `int`, wondering how `strlen` would interpret those bytes even though they are manifestly *not* a proper C string, that's a completely different question.

Comment: @tadman: You can use `strlen` on a pointer to any object converted to `char *` provided the object contains a zero byte. The C standard syntax specifies all objects are represented by bytes and may be accessed as a character type, which is what `sten` is specified to do (in effective behavior).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I get that, but it's just that a large portion of possible `int` values will not have zeroes. You'll need to be very careful when operating this way.

Comment: I suggest you find (or better yet, write yourself) a proper hexdump function, and use that to help gain understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `strlen` on an `int` array. The function's name already suggested it should only be used on legally formed C strings.

That being said, for the reason of studying, array `v`'s memory layout looks something like this on a little-endian machine:

```
    ff ff ff ff e8 03 00 00 02 00 00 00 (00 onwards)
low 0>-^^----<0 1>-------<1 2>-------<2 3> ...----<9 high
```

Since you are calling `strlen((char *)v + 1)`, the computation starts at the location I marked with `^`. There're 5 non-zero elements (ff, ff, ff, e8, 03), so the result is 5, not 4. Remember 1000 == 0x3e8.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the bytes in V are represented as:

```
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,  ...
```

So after skipping the first byte (not the first int, since you cast to char *) there are 5 bytes before the first '\0' character.

Answer (score 3):

This little demo can help you clarify how bytes are ordered in little-endian machine (presuming every thing is as written above):

```
char* z = (char*)v + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%02x ", (uint8_t)z[i]);
```

the print out should be like this:
`ff ff ff e8 03 00 00 02 00 00` (like Harlan Wei showed above).

this little snippet can also help you see how bytes are stored in big-endian machines too. So mere counting should give you 5 not 4 as strlen(...) was trying to say.

Comment: I've used the wrong code before, apologies; I tested this one out, it should explain it well.